# Are my derivative computations correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, normed-spaces

I am trying to program this but I need to verify if the equations I have are correct

$$ f(x) = ||x||^3 + \frac{m}{2} \times ||x||^2 $$

$$ \text{gradient of f(x) = } 3||x||^2 + m \times x $$
$$ \text{hessian=  } 6||x|| + m $$

if this understanding is correct.

And I start with x in $\mathbb{R}^5$ i.e. a $5\times1$ vector, when I solve for hessian using equation 3, I don't get a matrix. I only get a row vector ($1\times5$)

||x|| implies Euclidean norm, m is a scalar (but I have been making m a $1\times5$ vector to match dimensions of x in my code)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your gradient is definitely not correct and so is the Hessian. Check the derivation formulas there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should start to compute derivative in a single element manner.
$$
f(\mathbf{x})= 
\left[ x_1^2+\ldots+x_N^2 \right]^{3/2}
+
\frac{m}{2}
\left[ x_1^2+\ldots+x_N^2 \right]
$$
Thus using chain rule for the first term
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}
= \frac32 \cdot (2x_n) \left[ x_1^2+\ldots+x_N^2 \right]^{1/2}
+ m x_n
=
3 \| \mathbf{x} \| x_n
+ m x_n
$$
Arranging the gradient in a column vector,
$$
\mathbf{g}
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
= (3\| \mathbf{x} \|+m) \mathbf{x}
$$

Repeat for the Hessian by computing
$H_{mn}=\frac{\partial g_m}{\partial x_n}$